# ASP.NET Core MVC Identity login issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identity

I am facing issues with Microsoft Identity using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC.

When logging successfully it says that user logged in but *it does not re-direct to default home page*. I think the reason that it does not re direct to home page is that because there are not cookies set because even when I successfully log in it redirects to login again instead of home page and having a cookie. PD: I am running only in http, I'm not using https because I don't have money for a certificate, I think it does not matter?

Where does it say that the user is logged in?

In the console:

[image]

but nothing happens, just redirects to login again and other controller views are blocked:

[image]

Controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    // private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    // private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        // IEmailSender emailSender,
        // ISmsSender smsSender,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        // _emailSender = emailSender;
        // _smsSender = smsSender;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            // {
            //     return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            // }

            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Register(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                // Send an email with this link
                //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                //    "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.100"));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("farmaowl")));

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
            .AddSignInManager()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddIdentityCookies(o => { });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Recepcion}/{action=Habitaciones}/{id?}");
        });

        // app.UseMvc(routes =>
        // {
        //     routes.MapRoute(
        //         name: "default",
        //         template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        // });
    }
}
```

I was following this code: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc

What am I missing? Am I missing any other necessary file or any other configuration? I am new with Identity using ASP.NET Core MVC (not new in ASP.NET MVC normal). Is it a cookie issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your middleware is wrong, the correct order should be

```
app.UseAuthentication();   
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Too much time struggling with this issue and you solved it in 1 min. You re a hero! wait 7 min so I can mark this as solved.